# How to play alarm based on user enter value into edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi want to play alarm in my app,so i tried using below code using services when i click start button alarm is playing..but what i want is,same activity i have two editexts in  first i have  give time 9,and second edittext  i have given time 10,so i have to show notification only in 9 and 10 pm only...any one give me some idea.

```
    public class DonnsAlarm extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText e1,e2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);



    // click listener for the button to start service
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               String s1=e1.getText().toString();
                String s2=e2.getText().toString();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(s1));


        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        Intent intent = new Intent(DonnsAlarm.this, Service_class.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DonnsAlarm.this, 0, intent,
                0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                36000 * 1000, pintent);


 PendingIntent pintent1 = PendingIntent.getService(DonnsAlarm.this, 1, intent,
                0);

 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(s2));
  alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                36000 * 1000, pintent1);




        }
    });

    // click listener for the button to stop service
    Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Service_class.class));
        }
    });
}
      }
    public class Service_class extends Service {

 @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notifyIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), DonnsAlarm.class);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence from ="It's Time to Play VocCards!";
        CharSequence message = "It's Time to Play VocCards!";

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);


        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
             "It's Time to Play VocCards!", System.currentTimeMillis());
       notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, contentIntent);
        nm.notify(1, notif);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem is giving the values of EditTexts to service so service knows which hours to play the alarm. You can put the values of EditText to a bundle (or intent's extras) and start the service using that intent which contains data about the hours.

In your Activity use:

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String s1=e1.getText().toString();
        String s2=e2.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Service_class.class);
        intent.putExtra("value1", s1);
        intent.putExtra("value2", s2);
        startService(intent);

    }
});
```

Than in your Service's onStartCommand method use this:

```
String val1 = intent.getExtra("value1");
String val2 = intent.getExtra("value2");
```

And now you have the values in your service!

Comment: thnkyou,but in service how have to check if the edittext value equles to system timing,those two values equles means inside i have to keep condition

Comment: hi inside service class i am giving condition like that.. if(val1.equals(System.currentTimeMillis())||val2.equals(System.currentTimeMillis()))
         {
         Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
         r.play();
         }
         else
         {
          
         } but am not two values are not maching,thats why my alaram not playing

Answer (score 0):

```
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s1=e1.getText().toString();
                String s2=e2.getText().toString();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(s1));


        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        Intent intent = new Intent(DonnsAlarm.this, Service_class.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DonnsAlarm.this, 0, intent,
                0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                36000 * 1000, pintent);


 PendingIntent pintent1 = PendingIntent.getService(DonnsAlarm.this, 1, intent,
                0);

 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(s2));
  alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                36000 * 1000, pintent1);



            }
        });
```

The above code sets the two alarm one according to the value in 1st edittext and one according to the other

Comment: hi i did what u said like that,but when i click button that time itself notification shwing..i edited my question can u see once